# Как реализовать телеграм бота на Python который принимает данные и выявляет есть ли Болезнь Паркинсона?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, jupyter-notebook, python-telegram-bot

Здраствуйте дамы и господа,у меня очень сложный и большой вопрос

Помогите реализовать телеграм бота на языке программировании python который принимает данные и через эти данные  вычисляет есть ли у этого человека болезнь Паркинсона.

Есть датасет **parkinson.data** (ниже прикреплю cсылку).У него 24 атрибута и каждый атрибут это параметры голоса человека.Python через эти данные вычисляет наличие болезни у этого человека.Пример:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В конце если status 1 то положительно,0-отрицательно.Теперь Я хочу написать бота который принимает такие же данные и в конце выдает сообщение  или True False.Помогите как это можно реализовать?

Ссылка на датасет:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/parkinsons/parkinsons.data

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как и любую другую задачу из области машинного обучения. Алгоритм традиционен.

1. Сначала выбираете какой метод классификации использовать и обучаете его на своих данных. В вашем случае  могут сработать как традиционные алгоритмы типа kNN, так и деревья, леса. Возможно придется и до глубокого обучения добраться. Впрочем,для нейросетей у вас маловата данных, возможно придется озаботится расширением своего датасета.
2. Если классификатор дает хорошие результаты не тестовых данных -  переходите к шагу три,  в противном случае пытаетесь применить другой метод классификации и переходите к шагу 1.
3. После обучения и верификации модели передаете ее в "продакшен". Т.е. встраиваете ее в вами написанный бот.
4. При поступлении новых данных передаете их на обученную модель и она вам выдает ваш диагноз.

Я надеюсь, что такое методы машинного обучения, какие они бывают и как ими пользоваться вы знаете. Вы также должны освоить соответствующие реализации. Если вы запостили вопрос под тегом Python -  то придется изучить scipy, scikit-learn, возможно и что-то из нейросетей -  TensorFlow, Keras. Кроме того, вы освоили программирование и умеете писать ботов. Если нет -  то надо будет все это предварительно изучить.

Будут конкретные вопросы  -  задавайте.